# What is the best way to document and keep a change log with azure?

Tags: azure, logging, documentation

We're looking for a lightweight solution that keeps track of our reasons and execution of changes made to azure tenant, there is no approval processes necessary but we would like a tracking system that allows us to easily and quickly catch up on history and existing state.

Answer (score 0):

By default, everything you do to an azure resource is recorded in the azure activity log. You can learn more about it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/platform-logs-overview). But I would recommend enabling Diagnostic Logging to your default Log Analytics workspace which will be part of your Azure Monitor Logs now. Learn more about Diagnostic Logging from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings).